# How can I run an php code inside html (test.html) file?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

How do I display PHP code in HTML? If this can be done by using .htaccess file,

1. can I use it on local server (like wamp)?
2. can anyone provide a sample .htaccess file for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run PHP with any extension you want. With Apache, you can simply add the following to your `.htaccess`

```
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .html .php .whatever
```

Comment: can I run this code in local server (wamp) ? PHP version - 5.5.12 and Apache version - 2.4.9

Answer (score 0):

You can't run php in an html page ending with .html
But unless the page is PHP and the extension was changed with .htaccess from .php to .html

And use it in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Read more at [How to hide extension PHP, HTML, HTM with .htaccess](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)